# WPF Design Time Eventhandler

Tags: c#, wpf, design-time

How to handle design time events?

More specifically if I am creating a custom TabMenu that can be used like this:

```
<Controls:TabMenu Orientation="Horizontal" Container="{Binding ElementName=gridContainer}">
    <Controls:TabItem Header="Header">
        <Grid>
            //Tab content
        </Grid>
    </Controls:TabItem>
    <Controls:TabItem Header="Empty tab"/>
</Controls:TabMenu>

//Load the tab content here
<Grid x:Name="gridDisplay" />
```

I want the **TabMenu** to load the **TabItem** *content* into my **Container** when selecting any of the **TabItem**'s in the designer,

I can load the first **TabItem**'s Content into the **Container** by using this in the **TabMenu** *Loaded* event;

```
if (stackHost.Children.Count > 0)
{
    TabItem firstItem = (TabItem)stackHost.Children[0];
    SelectTab(firstItem);
}
```

Note: The **TabItem**'s *MouseDown* event is not triggered design time.

Answer (score 0):

The existing designer intercepts everything. You have to create a custom designer if you want to do custom stuff:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675304(v=vs.110).aspx

Disclaimer: Not much info available out there about this :).